# Problem trying to build a stand-alone QGIS application with Unbuntu Trusty system

Tags: qgis

I'm currently reading the "Building Mapping Applications with QGIS" Book and I'm stumped when I try to set my paths in Ubuntu.

The first command works fine:
export PYTHONPATH=~/usr/share/qgis/python/

The command to set my QGIS libraries is an issue:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/qgis path/lib

The issue is that I can't find the "lib" directory.

From what I can see qgis executes from the "/usr/bin/qgis" folder
It's files are located in the "~/usr/share/qgis" folders but there is no hint of a lib folder

I do have the following under the qgis structure:
-doc
-globe
-grass
-i18n
-images
-python
-resources
-svg

Can someone figure out how to set the qgis/lib path under ubuntu trusty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had installed anaconda on my system.  When I invoked python from the command line it was booting the anaconda version of python and it couldn't find the qgis.core or qgis.gui libraries.

I went ahead and uninstalled anaconda.  This time when I ran python it ran the imports properly.

Looks like I'm good to go.

Comment: Can you please *accept this answer* as the correct one (the little tick mark on the left) so people in the future know what the problem was and how to solve it.